# Optimization of menu and submenu in c++

Tags: c++, menu

I have created a menu with four options and when you choose one of the option the will redirect you to another submenu where for example there is two options and after that the program will do what they have to do. I success to do this, but my problem is I want to optimize this so that all the possibilities that user inserts will be one the same function Menu_select() in order to code properly. For example, if the user choose the option 2 and after this the option 1 all this will be manage under the Menu_select() and not that in every submenu I will have if choose (x) do x and if choose (y) do (y). To sumb up I want to bring together under the same function all the option that the user can choose.

This is my code:

```
int Shop::Menu_select(int choose)
{
    switch (choose)
    {
    case 1:
        break;
    case 2:
        Menu_Video();
        break;
    case 3:
        break;
    case 4:
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
void Shop::Menu()
{
    int choose = 0;
    cout << "Rony Dvd Rental Shop !" << endl;
    cout << "1.Customer" << endl;
    cout << "2.Dvd" << endl;
    cout << "3.Rental" << endl;
    cout << "4.Exit" << endl;

    cout << endl << "Choose an option: ";
    cin >> choose;

    Menu_select(choose);
}
void Shop::Menu_Video()
{
    int choose = 0;

    system("cls");
    cout << "1.Add Dvd to the store " << endl;
    cout << "2.Delete Dvd from the store " << endl;

    cout << endl << "Choose an option: "; 
    cin >> choose;

    if (choose == 1)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "You want to add Dvd to the store" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "You want to delete Dvd from the store" << endl;
    }


}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can optimise as per following example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int menu(string mArray[],int menuLength){
    int choosen = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<menuLength;i++)
      cout << mArray[i] << endl;
    cout << "Enter your choice -->" ;
    cin >> choosen;
   return choosen;
}

void menu_select(int select){
   switch(select){
     case 1:
       // for menu
       cout << "menu opt-1" << endl;
       break;
     case 2:
       cout << "menu opt-2" << endl;
       break;
     case 3:
       cout << "menu opt-3" << endl;
       break;
     case 4:
       cout << "menu opt-4" << endl;
       break;
     case 5:
     // for sub-menu
       cout << "sub-menu opt-1" << endl;
       break;
     case 6:
      // for sub-menu
        cout << "sub-menu opt-2" << endl;
        break;
     }
 }

int main(){

   string menu1[] = {"1.Option1","2.Option2","3.Option3","4.Option4"};
   string menu2[] = {"1.Option-1","2.Option-2"};

   int ch1=0,ch2=0;
   ch1 = menu(menu1,4);
   cout << "You entered:" << ch1 << endl;

   menu_select(ch1);
   ch2=menu(menu2,2);
   //sub-menu with options
   cout << "You entered:" << ch2 << endl;

   //check ch2 not zero
   menu_select(ch2+4); // if main menu has four options
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should do this with either QT or Win32(Windows only)libraries. This would increase functionality tremendously, and make your end product look better.

Here's some documentation.
for basic windows
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx 
for menu selection
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646977(v=vs.85).aspx